# Как объект поместить поверх всех объектов Unity

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть объект в данном случае босс в игре. Как его сделать по верх других объектов.[image: Нужно что бы был поверх фона]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В 3D видно что элемент стоит впереди, но задний фон все равно его перекрывает

Comment: z координата????

Comment: Не помогает, может я намудрил со слоями, точно понять не как не могу

Comment: Я добавил картинку, босса перекрывает задний фон, хотя задний фон по Z находится за боссом, я так понимаю дело в слоях.

Comment: Убедитесь, что у всех элементов scale по z больше нуля.

Comment: У всех элементов, scale по Z больше нуля, только я не понимаю для чего это

Comment: Да дело как я и предполагал было в слоях, выставил всем слоями заднего фона, включая и платформы, в Sprite Renderer -> Sorting Layer -> Default. Но с чем это было связано я так и не понял. На боссе нет Sprite Renderer, и все сработало.